# How to show that $-x^2\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) = y\mathrm{d}x-x\mathrm{d}y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I thought of replacing $\frac{y}{x}$ with a variable $z$ but this only got me into further confusion. I am very unfamiliar with manipulating single $\mathrm{d}$'s as opposed to ratios of them where your product rule and chain rule can come in useful. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just determine the differential as $du(x) = \frac{du(x) } {dx} dx$. Then your thing becomes $d(\frac{y} {x}) =\frac{(xdy - ydx)}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $y=y(x)$, then

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{y(x)}{x}\right)= \frac{xy'(x)-y(x)}{x^2}.$$

Hence

$$-x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\frac{y(x)}{x}\right)=y(x)-xy'(x).$$

Answer (score 0):

Just apply Leibniz rule, $d(f_1 f_2) = df_1 f_2 + f_1 d f_2$. You know $d\left(\frac{1}{x} \right) = - \frac{1}{x^2} dx$ then it automatically solves.